# sql add column with unique id's based on a certain value in two columns

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble creating the 'id' column for a table of my database. The id column adds an unique id to rows that have the same values in value1 and value2 including reverse.

I want to achieve the following:

```
value1, value2, id
  1      2      1
  1      2      1
  2      1      1
  3      4      2   
  4      3      2
  5      6      3
  6      7      4
```

I tried to create the id column by the following query in my select statement: (it only combines rows that have equal value1 and value2):

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN value1= value1 and value2= value1 THEN 1
    ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY value1,value2) AS id
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use;

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by (case when value1 < value2 then value1 else value2 end),
                                   (case when value1 < value2 then value2 else value1 end)
                         ) as group_id                                   
from t;
```

I should note that most databases support `greatest()` and `least()`, so this can be more simply written as:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by least(value1, value2), greatest(value1, value2)
                         ) as group_id                                   
from t;
```